# Python Tkinter "wait_window()" never continuing

Tags: python, tkinter, modal-dialog

I have a Tkinter app in python and I am trying to use a custom-defined dialog box in it. So I have a main `App` class and a `Dialog` class that extends `Toplevel`. Within the body of the `App` class a `Dialog` needs to pop up and allow the user to enter information which can then be passed to the main `App`.

I know that I need to use the `wait_window()` method so that the main app waits for the dialog to be destroyed before continuing in the code. But for some reason even after I exit the dialog box the program doesn't continue.

I have code that looks like

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        #more init code...
    #more unrelated methods...
    def analyze(self):
        dialog = Dialog()
        self.root.wait_window(dialog)
        print("Continuing...")
        #use the data collected in 'dialog'

class Dialog(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        #set up the components of the dialog
        #all input data gets saved as instance variables so I can access it
        self.mainloop()
    def destroy(self):
        print("Destroying")
        Toplevel.destroy(self)
```

When I run the app, the dialog box appears as intended, and works as intended. However, when I press the red X in the corner, the program does not continue. The dialog box closes and "Destroying" is printed so I know the `destroy` method is being called, but "Continuing" is not printed, nor is any of the data being used.

I tried adding a button to the dialog that calls `self.destroy` as its command to explicitly destroy it. I also tried not overriding the `destroy` method in `Dialog` to see if that was causing it but none of this worked.

I also treid doing `dialog.wait_window()` instead of `self.root.wait_window(dialog)` to see if that helped but it didn't.

Any help is much appreciated. If more code is needed I can provide it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `mainloop()` a second time. `mainloop()` should always be called exactly once for the life of the program.

Comment: Wow that worked!! Can you please explain to me why that did it? I am kind of new to Tkinter.

Comment: `mainloop()` is an infinite loop, so it never returns. You had an infinite loop running inside an infinite loop. It processes events just like the original call to `mainloop()` so it seemed like it returned, but it never did.